# awk print all parts before a match

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have some text where I want to grab all the text up to the year, inclusive. I've tried starting with something like this

```
awk '/[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]/{print $1}'
```

but that only prints the first "word" of the input

```
"Financial summary 1997 FINAL.doc" => "Financial"
"v4 Minutes 19950705" => "v4"
```

What I want is "Financial summary 1997" and "v4 Minutes 1995". I've played around with $NF and various others with no success as yet I don't know how many words there are, or how many numbers there are, so I can't jut print $1 $2 $3. I don't have to use awk, but it would be useful since I am actually going to print the results out with some surrounding tags for output to an HTML file.

I can set a field separator to be "4 digits" but that discards the year

```
 awk -F[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9] '{print $1}
```

EDIT:
This is what I ended up with and then came back to see a solution posted:

```
awk 'match($0,/.*(19|20)[0-9]{2}/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'
```

Thanks all

Comment: Can there be multiple numbers matching `[12][0-9]{3}` in the input string? If so, should the solution match up to the first one or the last one? (e.g. should `test1 1234 test2 1567 test3` return `test1 1234` or `test1 1234 test2 1567` ?)

Comment: It should match the first possible match, yes. So in the example "v4 Minutes 19950705" it should match 1995, not 9950 or 9507, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**awk** solution:

```
awk 'match($0,/.*\<[12][0-9]{3}/){ print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)"\042" }' file
```

The output:

```
"Financial summary 1997"
"v4 Minutes 1995"
```

Comment: Ok, but if the files is "v4 Minutes 1991111" the result is "v4 Minutes 1991111"

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `grep` command:

```
grep -oE '[^"]* [1-2][0-9]{3}' file

Financial summary 1997
v4 Minutes 1995
```

For `awk`, you can use `gensub`:

```
awk '{ print substr(gensub(/^(.* [1-2][0-9]{3}).*/, "\\1", "1"), 2) }' file

Financial summary 1997
v4 Minutes 1995
```

Comment: Could just do `[^"]*`, no need for perl.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r 's/(.*[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]).*/\1"/' input
"Financial summary 1997"
"v4 Minutes 1995"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{sub(/97/,"97\"");print $1,$2,$3}' file

"Financial summary 1997"
"v4 Minutes 19950705"
```

All we have to do is to print the three first fields 
and add a double quote after 1997. With the help of

sub the double is added but it has to be escaped first "\"
that is all.

Comment: This answer would be better with a bit of explanation of why it works.